# Exclude SerializedName field but only when its not set

Tags: java, serialization, gson

I have an object that I'm serializing to make requests.

```
private static final String JSON_REQUEST_ID = "requestId";
private static final String JSON_OBJECT_ID = "objectId";
private static final String JSON_GROUP_ID = "groupID";

@SerializedName(JSON_REQUEST_ID)
public String requestId;

@SerializedName(JSON_OBJECT_ID)
public String objectId;

@SerializedName(JSON_GROUP_ID)
public String groupId;
```

When I send this data off to be processed the `objectId` and `groupId` need to be exclusive. So if I set the `objectId` I must remove the `groupId`, and vice-versa, from the request.

Is there an easy way to annotate that or should I create a different class for each?

Comment: One option is to make fields private and creating setters for fields, so setters then set "the other" field null. But the best option is to create class for each by inheriting common fields, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using different classes would make it more obvious, since different outcome (different attributes) mean different json objects.

For "simplification" on your side, you can use the same java class and provide a custom serializer for this.